dmultinom yields a probability of zero
I am working with dmultinom function from the Stats package in R. I am trying to calculate the probability of observing these values:
observed_values <- c(23, 14, 81, 0, 0, 0, 154, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 50, 174, 7, 1719, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 738, 28, 1653, 17, 77, 2, 44, 242, 59, 0, 0, 23, 108, 14, 268, 22, 0, 22, 25, 0, 0, 268, 213, 0, 377, 10, 0, 200, 91, 0, 0, 0, 1231, 0, 122, 0, 0, 462, 322, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 233, 0, 31, 382, 484, 82, 31, 81, 48, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 93, 0, 0, 0, 4954, 111, 0, 0, 473)
from these probabilities:
[1] 0.0013982689 0.0059828432 0.0059828432 0.0199428108 0.0059828432 0.0001747836 [7] 0.0518513081 0.0008739181 0.0358970594 0.0179485297 0.0119656865 0.0059828432 [13] 0.0219370919 0.0059828432 0.0006991345 0.0019942811 0.0139599676 0.0239313730 [19] 0.0039885622 0.0001747836 0.0219370919 0.0159542486 0.0119656865 0.0039885622 [25] 0.0038452396 0.0039885622 0.0003495672 0.0290595243 0.0008739181 0.0047191577 [31] 0.0013982689 0.0059828432 0.0059828432 0.0199428108 0.0059828432 0.0001747836 [37] 0.0518513081 0.0008739181 0.0358970594 0.0179485297 0.0119656865 0.0059828432 [43] 0.0219370919 0.0059828432 0.0006991345 0.0019942811 0.0139599676 0.0239313730 [49] 0.0039885622 0.0001747836 0.0219370919 0.0159542486 0.0119656865 0.0039885622 [55] 0.0038452396 0.0039885622 0.0003495672 0.0290595243 0.0008739181 0.0047191577 [61] 0.0013982689 0.0059828432 0.0059828432 0.0199428108 0.0059828432 0.0001747836 [67] 0.0518513081 0.0008739181 0.0358970594 0.0179485297 0.0119656865 0.0059828432 [73] 0.0219370919 0.0059828432 0.0006991345 0.0019942811 0.0139599676 0.0239313730 [79] 0.0039885622 0.0001747836 0.0219370919 0.0159542486 0.0119656865 0.0039885622 [85] 0.0038452396 0.0039885622 0.0003495672 0.0290595243 0.0008739181 0.0047191577
The probability I get from dmultinom is always zero. Any advice on why this is happening ?
Alternatively one could try computing it with different probabilities ( for example a fair multinomial distribution), to try and figure out the issue,  but the observed values have to be exactly these ones, since this is from real life biological data.
Any advice would be more than welcome. Any other packages I could use apart from Stats ?
Thank you.
Everything seems to work with data generate randomly from R. but with real life data, it's not working.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It seems likely that the combination you've shown (c(23, 14, 81, ...)) just has very small probability under the stated probabilities -- recall that there are terms looking like (small number)^(large exponent) in the multinomial probability function. Try working with the logarithm of the probability if you can -- I don't know if there is a built-in function for that, or maybe you'll have to write it yourself.
